# How to test if a list has the same elements

Tags: python, list

In a nutshell, I would like to know how to compare lists in this situation...
I am creating a tic tac toe game and would like to test if the player has won or not.

```
WinningPossibilities = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
ThePlayersList = []
```

So, let's assume [ThePlayerList] has 4 things saved to it

```
WinningPossibilities = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
# Right Here 
#| |
#V V
ThePlayersList = [1,2,3,4]
```

How would I compare "if" the [ThePlayerList] is "In" [WinningPossibilities}, because clearly, the player has won, it would look like this;

```
 X | X | X
-----------
 X |   |   
-----------
   |   |
```

Originally I was thinking of typing;

```
if ThePlayerList in WinningPossibilities:
     print("The Player has won")
```

But it did not seem to work, I can't compare [1,2,3,4] to [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]] and see if it matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to ask this is: is it the case that for `any` of the `WinningPossibilities` `all` the numbers are in `ThePlayersList`. This translates pretty closely to python:

```
WinningPossibilities = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]
ThePlayersList = [1,2,3,4]

has_won = any(all(n in ThePlayersList for n in win) for win in WinningPossibilities)
# True
```

This is nice since the order doesn't matter: a list like `ThePlayersList = [4,2,3,1]` should still win even though that order doesn't appear in the winning possibilities.

And since order doesn't matter, you could simplify this a bit by using sets instead of lists:

```
WinningPossibilities = [{1, 2, 3},
 {4, 5, 6},
 {7, 8, 9},
 {1, 4, 7},
 {2, 5, 8},
 {3, 6, 9},
 {1, 5, 9},
 {3, 5, 7}]

ThePlayersList = {1,2,3,4}

has_won = any(win.issubset(ThePlayersList) for win in WinningPossibilities)
```